# Setting Nivo Slider background-position property on individual slides

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

I'm using jquery Nivo Slider. I want to set the background-position property for the div#slider element for each individual slide.

I presume I would use some switch like this:

```
    switch(vars.currentSlide)
        {
        case 0:
            slider.css('background-position', '-201px 0px');
            break;
        case 1:
            slider.css('background-position', '-45px 0px');
            break;
        case 2:         
            slider.css('background-position', '-192px 0px');
            break;
        case 3:
            slider.css('background-position', '-93px 0px');
            break;
        case 4:
            slider.css('background-position', '-32px 0px');
            break;
        case 5:
            slider.css('background-position', '-254px 0px');
            break;
        default:
            slider.css('background-position', '-201px 0px');
        };
```

Is this correct, and where do I put this switch in the nivo slider javascript? If not, can you please advise how?

On this [link to the page](http://rosenfarblaw.com/mockups/index_320.html) you can see that I successfully only did this for the initial slide, and it only works in the first instance (line 97 of the [nivo js](http://rosenfarblaw.com/js/narrow/jquery.nivo.slider.320.js) file.)